# Impossible to remove bearer cookie online

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, httponly, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm currently building an API with Symfony, to make the authentication secure I'm using the LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle with JWTRefreshTokenBundle and everything is setup so both the BEARER and refresh_token are send in a secure httponly cookie.
Here is my setup :

`security.yaml`

```
security:
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    api:
        pattern: ^/
        stateless: true
        entry_point: jwt
        jwt: ~
        json_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        refresh_jwt:
            check_path: /token/refresh
        logout:
            path: api_token_invalidate
            delete_cookies:
                BEARER: null
                refresh_token: null
```

`lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml`

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
user_identity_field: email
secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
token_ttl: 3600
token_extractors:
    cookie:
        enabled: true
        name: BEARER
set_cookies:
    BEARER:
        httpOnly: true
        samesite: none
        secure: true
        path: /
        domain: '%env(COOKIE_DOMAIN)%'
        lifetime: null
```

`gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.yaml`

```
gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token:
manager_type: mongodb
refresh_token_class: App\Document\RefreshToken
ttl: 86400
single_use: true
cookie:
    enabled: true
    remove_token_from_body: true
    http_only: true     
    same_site: none
    secure: true
    path: /
    domain: '%env(COOKIE_DOMAIN)%'
```

Everything works fine when I run it locally with Postman. When I log in, I get both cookies and when I log out both cookies are removed. But on production only the refresh_token cookie is removed. I am also sending a request with Postman so I don't think that the problem is the cookies themselves. As the cookies are httponly I can't access it from the front-end and being unable to remove the BEARER cookie is problematic because it leads users to be logged and unlogged at the same time.